# Adding to sql query to join data from another table to current table

Tags: sql, database, excel

I have two sqls in microsoft query below which are in two seperate excel files, i'd like to make one main bit of sql in one excel file which combines both sql codes - so that the second sql (3 columns of data [z.ANALYSTNAME, z.MASTERCITYCODE, z.MEXID]) joins onto the first sql table based on the first column in each s.code and z.code being the same. Please see the 2 sqls below which return two tables:

```
 `select
    distinct
    s.code as SEDOL, s.ISIN, s.Shortname as StockShortname, s.Fullname as 
StockFullname, s.Status as StockStatus,
    s.PriceKey as ExShareKey, s.IssueCcy as PriceCcy,
    s.Catagory as Catagory,
    decode(Catagory,'E','Equity','U','Unit Trust','G','Fixed Interest', 
catagory) as CatagoryFull,
    s.DealCCY as DealingCCY, s.IncomeCcy, s.EarningsCCY, s.noOfHolders, 
 s.Class as AssetClass, s.Depot as StockDepot,
    s.StampScale as StampScale, s.REIT as REITFlag, s.LastBid,s.LastOffer, 
S.PriceDate as LastPriceDate,
    s.SecGroup as AssetGroup, ts.Fullname as AssetGroupDesc, ts.ShortName as 
AssetGroupShort,
    s.SecTypes as AssetType, tt.Fullname as AssetTypeDesc, tt.ShortName as 
AssetTypeShort,
    s.Indust as AssetSector, ti.Fullname as AssetSectorDesc,
    s.Secmicropal as AssetSubSector, tm.Fullname as AseetSubSectorDesc,
    s.SecCustom as AssetCustom, tsc.Fullname as AssetCustomDesc,
    s.dealstyle as assetDealStyle,
    ex.PriceFeed_code as exsharepricecode, ex.Country_Of_Incorporation as 
exsharecoi
    , round(nvl(h.Quantity,0),2) as TotalHoldingUnits
    , round(nvl(h.Quantity,0)*((s.LastBid+s.LastOffer)/2 + 
nvl(s.Accrued/100,0))/cs.LastBid,2) as HoldingsValueGBP
, sysdate as ValuesAsAtDate
    , nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type)) as RiskNumber,
    case
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=1 then 0
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=2 then 0
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=3 then 0
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=4 then 0.5
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=5 then 0.5
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=6 then 0.5
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=7 then 1
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=8 then 1
        when nvl(s.risk_rating,nvl(tm.type,ti.Type))=9 then 1
        else null
    end as EqRiskWeight,
    s.Recommendation as StockRecommendation, s.recommenddate as 
RecommendationDate,
    s.ShareBenefits1 as Benefits1AlternateShareClass, s.ShareBenefits2 as 
ResearchStyle,
    s.ShareBenefits3 as PriceTarget, s.ShareBenefits4 as HouseModel,
FROM    cpam.Security s,
    cpam.TableSecGroup ts, cpam.TableSecTypes tt, cpam.TableIndust ti, 
cpam.TableSecmpal tm, cpam.TableSecCustom tsc,
    cpam.ExShare ex, 
    (SELECT     h.Asset, sum(h.Quantity) as Quantity
        FROM    cpam.Holdings h
        WHERE   h.status='A' and h.Quantity<>0
        GROUP BY h.Asset) h,
    cpam.Currencies cs
WHERE   s.Class = 'S' and s.code is not null 
    and S.SecGroup = ts.code(+)
    and S.SecTypes = tt.code(+)
    and S.Indust = ti.code(+)
    and S.Secmicropal = tm.code(+)
    and S.PriceKey = ex.code (+)
    and s.SecCustom = tsc.code(+)
    and s.code = h.asset(+)
    and s.IssueCcy = cs.Code(+) 
ORDER BY S.Shortname`
```

And second table:

```
'SELECT z.code, z.ANALYSTNAME, z.MASTERCITYCODE, z.MEXID
FROM CPAM_QRY.VIEW_CAM_STOCK_UNIV_STKDATA z'
```

Comment: Please drop the antiquated implicit join syntax and switch to 'modern' (already 25 years ANSI) explicit `join` syntax. Also, I don't understand your question, why don't you simply join the subquery? You already have one (`h`), so just do the same again.

Comment: My apologies - I am a newbie at sql, the first sql was provided to me, whereas I created the second sql - what does the    (h) imply?

Comment: i have updated my initial question so that it is hopefully more clear what i am trying to achieve - as I said I am brand new to the ropes of sql, I simply want to get the 3 columns of data that the second sql returns into the first sql so that I only use one file/sql code

Comment: You say `microsoft query`, but you use Oracle. `decode` and `nvl` are Oracle specific. You should simply join `CPAM_QRY.VIEW_CAM_STOCK_UNIV_STKDATA` to the rest of the query, and add the columns you want to the `select`

Comment: Also, and I don't mean to sound unfriendly, if you are that new to sql, maybe you should follow a tutorial first. There are plenty of resources online. Stack Overflow is not really intended for 'rooky' questions like this (in fact, SO has a reputation for being quite hostile towards naive users).